# NetBeans 7.0 Beta Java Source Format - Concatenated Strings

Tags: java, netbeans, editor, string-formatting

NetBeans 7.0 beta features the Source Format (Alt+Shift+F) feature found in NetBeans 6; however, given code like:

`"This" +
"is" +
"a" +
"message"`

the Source Format feature re-writes it as:

`"This"
+ "is"
+ "a"
+ "message"`

This is undesirable since the majority of already-developed code is written the first way.  (This behavior also happens for boolean logic expressions).

This behavior was filed as a bug in NetBeans 6 and was fixed and closed:
 http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=177010

Is there a good way to re-format the source code (back to the first way) after NetBeans formats it?  My initial thought is to perform find and replace using regular expressions with capturing groups, but I don't know if that will work in all cases...

Comment: You should really re-open the bug. Whilst workarounds might be handy, it's better to fix it at the source.

Comment: I agree with @Catchwa on the strategy that you should take.

Comment: Thanks @Catchwa, I found a way to request re-opening the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to preferences, then select the editor group then select the formatting tab. Select the Java language and category wrapping. There is an option there Wrap after binary operators. Switching it on should help.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but maybe for other users this solution would work.

Comment: Do you have the first beta or the second? Mine is beta2.

Comment: I have beta1 although for other reasons I'm back to using NetBeans 6.9.1 for now.